# Creating a list view within a list view

Tags: android, listview

I am creating an android application that displays orders from two database tables.

One table displays the order_id and the other table displays the items for each order.

I want to display a list view of all the orders and within each order I want to display all the order items as follows:

Order 1
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3

Order 2
Item 4
Item 5, etc

So far I have only been able to return this as one list view which returns as follows:

Order1
Item1

Order1
Item2

Order1
Item3, etc

Any advice at all would be helpful, I am really struggling with this!

My code is as follows:

The activity where I want it to be shown:

```
ListView listView;
    List<ChefOrderList> listOrders;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chef_screen);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_chef_orders);
        listOrders = new ArrayList<>();

        displayOrders();
    }

    private void displayOrders(){
        String url = "hidden";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("orders");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject orderObj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        ChefOrderList c = new ChefOrderList(orderObj.getString("menu_item_name"), orderObj.getString("item_type"), orderObj.getString("order_date_time"),
                                orderObj.getInt("quantity_ordered"), orderObj.getInt("order_id"));
                        listOrders.add(c);


                    }
                    ChefOrderAdapter adapter = new ChefOrderAdapter(listOrders, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ChefScreen.this, "Oops!" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("menuid", "0");
                return params;
            }

        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

the model:

```
public class ChefOrderList {

   String Name, Type, Date;
    int Qty, Order;

    public ChefOrderList(String name, String type, String date, int qty, int order) {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Date = date;
        Qty = qty;
        Order = order;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return Qty;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return Order;
    }
}
```

the adapter:

```
private List<ChefOrderList> chefOrderList1;
    private Context context;

    public ChefOrderAdapter(List<ChefOrderList> M, Context C){
        super(C, R.layout.listcheforders, M);
        this.chefOrderList1 = M;
        this.context = C;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcheforders,null,true);

        TextView orderNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.tvOrderNumber);
        TextView itemType = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemType);
        TextView itemName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
        TextView orderQuantity = view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemQty);
        TextView orderTime = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDateTime);


        ChefOrderList chefOrderList = chefOrderList1.get(position);


        itemName.setText(chefOrderList.getName());
        orderQuantity.setText("Qty: " +chefOrderList.getQty());


        if(position>0){
            ChefOrderList prevChefOrderList = chefOrderList1.get(position-1);
            if(chefOrderList.getOrder() != (prevChefOrderList.getOrder())){
                orderNumber.setText("Order: " +chefOrderList.getOrder());

                orderTime.setText(chefOrderList.getDate());

            }

            if(!chefOrderList.getType().equals(prevChefOrderList.getType())){
                itemType.setText(chefOrderList.getType());
            }

        } else {

            itemType.setText(chefOrderList.getType());
            orderNumber.setText("Order: " +chefOrderList.getOrder());
            orderTime.setText(chefOrderList.getDate());
        }
        return view;

    }
```

the query and table:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about have a model for Order and a model for Item.  Then your Order model can have a list of Item objects.  When you inflate your view in the list adapter you can loop through the items on the order object and create a new view and add it to the view that you are going to display